# Formatting a textfile python

Tags: python, escaping, character, newline

I am trying to format input into a text file like this:

```
    a
    b
    c
    d
```

What I am getting instead is:

```
    a

    b

    c

    d
```

This is the code I am using

```
f = open("testfile.txt", "r")
text = f.read()
text = str(text)
looper= text.count(",")
f.close()
god= open("dog.txt","a")
god.write("Passwords:")
god.close()
for count in range(looper):
    block = ""
    first= (text.find(':'))
    second= (text.find(','))
    block= text[first:second]
    text = text[second:]
    text = text[first:]
    print (block)
    god= open("dog.txt","a")
    god.write("\n"+block)
    god.close()
```

The code I am focusing on though is:

```
    god= open("dog.txt", "a")
    god.wring("\n"+block)
    god.close()
```

The input for testing.txt is:

```
    item1:A,
    item2:B,
    item3:C,
```

Comment: check what is `block`. it might have `\n` as well. So it ends up adding 2 newlines char `\n`.

Comment: @Rohanil it should not have a \n when its created though right.

Comment: how is your `testfile.txt`? I tried with `usr1:pwd1,usr2:pwd2,usr3:pwd3,usr4:pwd4,` and it worked fine without extra lines.

Comment: I am pulling them from testfile.txt and each string is spaced on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm assuming the following content of testfile:

```
key1:abcde,key2:fghij,key3:klmno,
```

Here's the code:

```
with open("testfile.txt") as f:
    text = f.read()
    looper = text.count(',')

with open("dog.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("Passwords:\n")

    for count in range(looper):
        first  = (text.find(':'))
        second = (text.find(','))
        block  = text[first+1:second]
        text   = text[second:]
        text   = text[first:]
        f.write(block + '\n')
```

Contents of the file 'dog.txt':

```
Passwords:
abcde
fghij
klmno
```

A shorter way to do it (first remove the comma at the end of "testfile.txt"):

```
with open("testfile.txt") as f:
    lst = f.read().strip('\n').split(',')

with open("dog.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("Passwords:\n")

    for item in lst:
        key,value=item.split(':')
        f.write(value + '\n')
```

Comment: I was just using abcd as examples when I am using a list of words that I don't know so I can use this method.

Comment: okay, I changed block to be a 'list of words'.  Is the output above now what you wanted?

Comment: not a literal list of words. The strings I am adding are unknown to me before I format them.

Comment: okay, I've made the changes, assuming a particular formatting for 'testfile.txt'

Answer (score 0):

check what is `block`. it might have `\n` as well. So it ends up adding 2 newlines char `\n`. Try without adding extra `\n` like

```
god= open("dog.txt","a")
god.write(block)
god.close()
```

or try using `strip` on `block`

```
god= open("dog.txt","a")
god.write("\n" + block.strip())
god.close()
```

Comment: When I did it without \n it formats like this:  :item1:item2:item3:item4